# Visual Studio Professional 2010 .csproj cannot be opened

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, x86-64, csproj, servicepacks

I am more In to Java, iOS, Linux. I did so little development with Microsoft products.

I am trying to run an existing project developed by another team on Microsoft visual studio.

The project is originality developed by Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

It is complaining that `.csproj cannot be opened`

I have noticed that so many ask this question in order to solve this based on the solution given, I try the following:

- run it on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 premium
- run it on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
- run it on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional
- installed service pack 1
- installed asp.net MVC 4
- re-applied service pack 1
- installed ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update
- installed webmatrix

Still the same problem.

I don't know why all this craps are needed to run one project. It looks for me intentional complication.

any one any other solution?

attached the beginning of the file as an image file.[image: link]

Comment: Any idea what kind of project? If you don't have the project type template installed locally, you will not be able to open it. See http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx

Comment: Could you add csproj content. The tag need to answer is projectguids

Comment: I doubt it says ".csproj cannot be opened".  What does it *really* say and what is in the file?  Look at it with, say, notepad.  Show the differences from a .csproj file you create yourself.

Comment: It says:   C:\xx\xx\xx.Web.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\xx\xx\xx.Web.csproj' cannot be opened.

Comment: It's likely a project file that was created in VS 2012.  The project files *seem* to be backward compatible only when the're created in 2010.   If you can open the solution fine in 2012, that's the most common problem I've encountered w.r.t. ".csproj cannot be opened".

Comment: @HansPassant Yep, I've encountered the dialog "project.csproj cannot be opened" and that was the only message.  Unbelievable but true.

Comment: @Peter are you recommending to run it on V.Studio Professional 2012?

Comment: @shebelaw I'm suggesting you try on VS 2012 and if it works, it's likely a VS 2012 project that is not compatible with 2010.

Comment: I am installing 2012 now. I doubt it is going to work

Comment: works fine with visual studio professional 2012. Now trying to edit the connection string so that the DB is pointed to to my local Microsoft SQL Server 2012